# Is there any way to use Emmet CSS abreviations with React Native?

Tags: css, react-native, emmet

I'm coming to React Native from React, and I write my CSS using pretty much only Emmet abbreviations.

Is there any way to use them with React Native?

For example:

`aic` becomes `align-items: center;` and `jcsb` becomes `justify-content: space-between;` in CSS with Emmet.

Answer (score 1):

About 3 minutes later I've found [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=carbonid1.emmet-jss) which works even if you're not using JSS.

It's called Emmet JSS by Andrew Korin (leaving the name here in case the link dies in the future)